# Find the directory that starts with a specific name using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to read a file that starts with the name VCALogParser_output_ARW.log, VCALogParser_output_CZC.log and so on. But In the same directory there is also files with the name VCALogParser_output_ARW_previous.log,VCALogParser_output_CZC_previous.log and so on. but I want to read only the files like VCALogParser_output_ARW.log. 
I tried doing like as below but it is reading both VCALogParser_output_ARW.log and VCALogParser_output_ARW_previous.log. can someone tell me how to do that ?

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.match`:

```
if re.match('VCALogParser_output_[A-Z]+\.log', filename):
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the files you're not interested also start with `VCALogParser_output`. You can add a term concerning the end of the file with the method [`endswith`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/endswith.html).

Try the following

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output'): 
            if not filename.endswith('_previous.log'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Using endswith() should do the job:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
for filename in filenames:
    if (filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output') and (not filename.endswith('previous.log'))):
```